# I'm able to read Gmail with Gnus, but not sending: cannot infer SMTP

Tags: gnus

### Setup:

GUI version GNU Emacs 25.0.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.16.7)
of 2015-11-02, from emacs-snapshot.

Linux Ubuntu distrubition

Gnus version 5.13

### Situation:

I switched to Linux, to be able to read my own mail.

When I'm reading my mail, I would like to reply it.

When I type my answer in the message window, and I send it with <kbd>C-c C-s</kbd>, I get the error messages:

```
Sending...
Sending via mail...
let*: Cannot infer SMTP
information.
```

When Googling around, it seems none had stumbled this issue earlier. I found only the contents of the Lisp code that produces this error message. It seems my SMTP is unknown to Gnus.

But how could I solve it? Gnus seems to have access to my Gmail.

Comment: I use C-c C-c to send, never knew about C-c C-s :-)

Comment: Can you please share with us your email configuration?

Comment: Your error seems to code similar on the following emacswiki page : https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleSMTPAccounts. Check your configuration for possibly wrong `gnus-posting-styles` and/or other settings.

Comment: @rimero thanks for your reply! It's appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First, please use stable version (24.3, 24.4, 24.5), many people reported v25 snapshot has weird bug. Don't use 25 until it's official released on http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/

Second, make sure GnuTLS and OpenSSH are installed. They should be installed on ubuntu by default. but it never hurts to double check.

Third, read my https://github.com/redguardtoo/mastering-emacs-in-one-year-guide/blob/master/gnus-guide-en.org. It includes all the information to use Gmail in Gnus. At minimum, you need check my sample ~/.gnus.el and ~/.authinfo.gpg